# ubuntu : [InvalidArgumentException] /app/config/dev/config.yml" does not exist - symfony 2.8- cannot run app/console commands

Tags: symfony, ubuntu

Hi we have deployed symfony 2.8 to qa environment and we have in app/config folder called "qa" with the config.
everything is work great and we set the environment in apache to "qa"
the site and deploy works fine.

the problem is that we cannot run **app/console command** or **fos/user commmand**.(asset:install) for example

the exception is :

```
[InvalidArgumentException] /app/config/dev/config.yml" does not exist
```

but it should not exist because we are in qa and not in dev env

please help
thx

Answer (score 0):

> but it should not exist because we are in qa and not in dev env

It *should* exist, because `config.yml` is the global config file used by *all* environments. The configuration in this file is overridden (partially) by the configuration in `config_dev.yml`, `config_prod.yml`, etc.

Put your default configuration in `config.yml` and put only the environment-specific configuration in `config_<env>.yml`.